# How to know if my location equal to a constant location

Tags: android, location

hi i am new to android and  trying to set a string if device's location equal to a specific location.like the following:

```
if (DeviceLocation == SpecificLocation) {
    String s = "Location Find";
}
```

please help.

Comment: Have you tried anything in particular, have you got code that is failing or that you are stuck on?

Comment: 1. how do i find the device location. 2. how do i compare it to a specific location. 3. how do i allow for accuracy tolerance. Stackoverflow is great for answering specific questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To compare two locations, you can use [distanceBetween()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceBetween(double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20float[])) or [distanceTo()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceTo(android.location.Location)).

They will return the approximate distance *in meters* between two locations.

eg:

```
float[] distance = new float[1];
Location.distanceBetween(lat, lon, currentLat, currentLon, distance);
if (distance[0] < 2.0) {
    String s = "Location Found";
}
```

Another option, is to compare `Latitude` and `Longitude` of your locations.

Answer (score 0):

You have to compare the last known location with what location you like using the Location class. (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html)
At the beginning you have to implement the location services. 
See: http://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html after you have already implemented it you will be able to compare with your location. (you need to know the coordinates of your location you like)